# Prometheus metrics error "was collected before with the same name and label values"

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics, observability

I have this service made in `go` that exposes RESTful API. I have a middleware that keeps track of requests via prometheus metrics (countervec and histogram) -> `requests_total` and `request_duration`. Every time a request comes in, the middleware calls 2 functions that pump the number up and log the duration of the request.

It has been happening sporadically. Sporadically as in when the service just springs up, it runs for a bit, throws the error, retries and then eventually crashes and stop producing metrics. Please check the error below

I want to know if anyone has encountered this error before and knows how to fix or debug the issue. I am speculating it is a race condition problem but I am not sure how to debug it with the knowledge and tools i have. Like: How do i replicate this issue via unit tests?

```
4 error(s) occurred:
* collected metric "omittedPart_request_total_6687cdb68f_2wqht" { label:<name:"method" value:"POS" > label:<name:"path" value:"/api/someService/user/:user_id" > label:<name:"servicename" value:"some-service" > label:<name:"status_code" value:"204" > counter:<value:1 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "omittedPart_request_total_6687cdb68f_2wqht" { label:<name:"method" value:"POST" > label:<name:"path" value:"/api/someService" > label:<name:"servicename" value:"some-service" > label:<name:"status_code" value:"200" > counter:<value:39 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "omittedPart_request_total_6687cdb68f_2wqht" { label:<name:"method" value:"GETT" > label:<name:"path" value:"/api/someService" > label:<name:"servicename" value:"some-service" > label:<name:"status_code" value:"200" > counter:<value:1 > } was collected before with the same name and label values
* collected metric "omittedPart_request_duration_seconds_6687cdb68f_2wqht" { label:<name:"method" value:"POST" > label:<name:"path" value:"/api/ujt" > label:<name:"servicename" value:"some-service" > label:<name:"status_code" value:"200" > histogram:<sample_count:39 sample_sum:0.38108896699999995 bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:1e-09 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:2e-09 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5e-09 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:1e-08 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:2e-08 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5e-08 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:1e-07 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:2e-07 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5e-07 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:1e-06 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:2e-06 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5e-06 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:1e-05 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:2e-05 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:5e-05 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.0001 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.0002 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.0005 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.001 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.002 > bucket:<cumulative_count:0 upper_bound:0.005 > bucket:<cumulative_count:33 upper_bound:0.01 > bucket:<cumulative_count:38 upper_bound:0.02 > bucket:<cumulative_count:38 upper_bound:0.05 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:0.1 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:0.2 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:0.5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:1 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:2 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:5 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:10 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:15 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:20 > bucket:<cumulative_count:39 upper_bound:30 > > } was collected before with the same name and label values
```

**More Context**

- The services are running in a kubernetes cluster as pods (via deployment)
- The metrics i am exposing are unique to each pod -> I am appending a GUID on the metric
- My implementation is something similar to the basic implementation of it [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#hdr-A_Basic_Example)
- Using [fiber.go](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber) to create our APIs and calling the functions to pump the metrics up via custom http handler as middleware
- I am using [client_golang v1.15.0](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang) as our metrics library

Any help would be appreciated and Thank you!

- I tried adding a lock (via mutex) on the functions calling the metric but the error is still happening

Comment: [Divide and conquer in debugging](https://betterprogramming.pub/find-and-fix-bugs-like-a-pro-with-divide-and-conquer-d55f3cf91154). Check if the same happening: if metrics collection disabled, if duration logging disabled, if only one of metrics is collected, an so on.

Comment: @markalex too bad the linked article is now behind a paywall ...